# bootstrap contact_me being submitted from another button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, contact-form

I am using the bootstrap contact_form with the contact_me.js and contact_me.php for my contact form submission. The problem I have is that I have a one page site and further up the page is a paypal button. when I click the paypal button, it is submitting the contact form.

I have tried to do a 'return false' on the paypal button to stop this and then have a jquery function for the paypal button click that submits the paypal form

Heres my paypal form

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name='paypalForm' method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="G8FJ3NGXWAE6G">
  <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Reservations">Reservations:<br />

  <select name="os0">
    <option value="One Bike">One Bike &euro;300.00</option>
    <option value="Two Bikes">Two Bikes &euro;600.00</option>
    <option value="Three Bikes">Three Bikes &euro;900.00</option>
  </select> 
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"><br />
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="button"  onclick="return false;"id='paypalButton' alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Heres my jquery on click function(I put the alert in to check its being called)

```
$( "#paypalButton" ).click(function() {     
            alert('here');
            $( "#paypalForm" ).submit();
        });
```

Here is the opening of the contact_me.js that is called if I dont have a 'return false' on the paypal button

```
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // something to have when submit produces an error ?
        // Not decided if I need it yet
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }......... etc
```

How can I get the paypal button to submit without submitting the contact form?

Do I have to change the contact_me.js(and how) or can I do it from the $('#paypalButton').click()  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the name of the form to the contactme.js file so that the submit call is like this

```
$('form[name="sentMessage"]').find("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
```

instead of

```
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
```

now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i tried something. I must admit that I am totally new to js and dont know if the following solution is bulletproof but both my PayPal button and the contactform are working now. Here is what i have done:

I went through the jqBootstrapValidation.js file and incrementally disabled parts of it until I found the spot that made my PayPal button work again. I found out that if line 49 of the js file:

```
var $inputs = $form.find("input,textarea,select").not("[type=submit],[type=image]").filter(settings.options.filter);
```

is disabled, the PayPal button works fine.

So next I wrapped the var into an if statement looking like this:

```
if (
     $form.hasClass("contactform")
   ) {
     var $inputs = $form.find("input,textarea,select").not("[type=submit],[type=image]").filter(settings.options.filter);
      }
```

so basically now the class "contactform" is needed in the html file to set the var $inputs.

My Contactform HTML looks like this now:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-6">
    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" class="contactform" novalidate>
        <legend class="content-legend">Kontakt</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control content-form" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Bitte geben sie Ihren Namen ein" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" class="form-control content-form" placeholder="Mail" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Bitte geben Sie eine Mailadresse ein" />
```

[...] etc.

e.g. the form contains the class "contactform".

My PayPal Button HTML looks like this:

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypalbutton" target="_top" style="float:right;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxx">
    <input type="submit" value="Jetzt zahlungspflichtig Bestellen" border="0" name="submit" title="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal." class="btn btn-primary">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

e.g. the form does not contain the class "contactform". The var $inputs will not be set by the jqBootstrapValidation.js file and so it does not trigger what ever prevents the PayPal button from working.

I hope it helps.